# Fetch UTC Date offset based on date format

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, datetime, javascript-objects

I have date with format '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999-05:00'

Need to fetch utc offset value like 300, 330 etc.

Can someone help here.Any Answer without using moment.js is appreciated.

So extracting value -05:00 from '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999-05:00'

Comment: like `new Date('2021-05-01T23:59:59.999-05:00').getTimezoneOffset()`? not very reliable, but still...

Comment: It gives same offsetnew Date('2021-05-01T23:59:59.999-05:00').getTimezoneOffset()
-330
new Date('2021-05-01T23:59:59.999-06:00').getTimezoneOffset()
-330

Comment: Basically i need different value  '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999-05:00' is 330 and  '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999-06:00' is 390

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov—that returns the system offset for that date and time, not the offset in the timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [Date.getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) will only ever give you the offset between the client machine timezone and UTC, it *won't* give you the UTC offset as specified in the ISO date string.

Given that the dates are in [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, we can parse the UTC offset from the data, it will be in the format ±[hh]:[mm], ±[hh][mm],  ±[hh] or 'Z' for UTC / Zulu time.

Negative UTC offsets describe a time zone west of UTC±00:00, where the civil time is behind (or earlier) than UTC so the zone designator will look like "−03:00","−0300", or "−03".

Positive UTC offsets describe a time zone at or east of UTC±00:00, where the civil time is the same as or ahead (or later) than UTC so the zone designator will look like "+02:00","+0200", or "+02".

We'll use regular expressions to parse the timezone offsets, this will work on IE 11 too.

```js
function getUTCOffsetMinutes(isoDate) {
    // The pattern will be ±[hh]:[mm], ±[hh][mm], or ±[hh], or 'Z'
    const offsetPattern = /([+-]\d{2}|Z):?(\d{2})?\s*$/;
    if (!offsetPattern.test(isoDate)) {
        throw new Error("Cannot parse UTC offset.")
    }
    const result = offsetPattern.exec(isoDate);
    return (+result[1] || 0) * 60 + (+result[2] || 0);
}

const inputs = [
    '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999+12:00',
    '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999+10',
    '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999+0530',
    '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999+0300',
    '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999Z',
    '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999-05:00',
    '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999-07:00',
];

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    console.log('input:', inputs[i], 'offsetMinutes:', getUTCOffsetMinutes(inputs[i]));
}
```

Comment: And for offsets like GMT+0:53:28 (Europe/Berlin circa 1800)? ;-)

Comment: Will this work across all the browser including IE11

Comment: Here's the compatibility matrix for RegExp: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#browser_compatibility. Unfortunately named groups won't work for IE, though it should work for Edge 79+. One could use babel to work around this, or we could simply use basic group function to support earlier versions of IE.

Comment: I've added a version (getUTCOffsetMinutesIE) that will work on older browsers, including IE.

Comment: Initially this was posted is there any issue.  getUTCOffsetMinutes = (dateObj) => {
        const input = `${dateObj}`.trim();
        if (/Z$/.test(input)) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (/[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}$/.test(input)) {
            const [hour, min] = input.slice(-6).split(':').map(Number);
            return hour * 60 + min;
        }
        if (/[+-]\d{4}$/.test(input)) {
            const [hour, min] = [input.slice(-4, -2), input.slice(-2)].map(Number);
            return hour * 60 + min;
        }
        return '';
    };

Comment: There wasn't any issue really, I just felt the later iteration was simpler.. one could use whichever one wished!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same as [@TerryLennox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69029205/257182) but deals with:

1. Seconds in the offset—fairly common before 1900, added as decimal part of minutes
2. Missing offset—local, returns *undefined*

```js
function parseOffset(ts) {
  let [all,hr,min,sec] = (''+ts).match(/([+-]\d{2}|Z):?(\d{2})?:?(\d{2})?$/) || [];
  let sign = hr < 0 ? -1 : 1;
  return !all ? all :     // No match, return undefined
         hr == 'Z' ? 0 :
         hr * 60 + (min? sign * min : 0) + (sec? sign * sec / 60 : 0);
}

['2021-05-01T23:59:59.999-05:30',
 '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999+05:30',
 '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999-0530',
 '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999+0530',
 '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999-05',
 '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999+05',
 '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999+053012',
 '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999+05:30:12',
 '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999Z',
 '2021-05-01T23:59:59.999',
 'blah'
].forEach(ts => console.log(ts + ' -> ' + parseOffset(ts)));
```